# Ignore X-frame-header using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, x-frame-options

I would like to ignore X-frame header on my website so that iframe can load external websites. There are chrome extension like 
[this](https://gist.github.com/dergachev/e216b25d9a144914eae2) one which works perfectly. How can I implement same concept through javascript?

Answer (score 5):

You can’t use frontend JavaScript code running in a browser to cause the `X-Frame-Options` response header to be ignored. `X-Frame-Options` is a security feature designed in part as a defense against clickjacking attacks. If any site could just use some JavaScript code to cause browsers to ignore `X-Frame-Options`, that would pretty much make it completely useless.

That’s the reason why the only way you can cause it to be  ignored in your own browser is by intentionally opting-in to insecure browsing by installing an extension as mentioned in the question.

But you can’t use JavaScript to force insecure browsing on other users by bypassing security features like `X-Frame-Options` that browsers have built-in support for.